# In Illustrator, switching from RGB to CMYK breaks "screen" blend mode

Tags: adobe-illustrator, blend-modes

In Illustrator, switching from RGB to CMYK breaks "screen" blend mode. Any idea how to keep the same aspect? I need CMYK.
[image: RVB]
[image: CMYK]

Answer (score 1):

Some blend modes are not possible with CMYK in Illustrator. There's nothing you can do about it.

The modes which rely on layer interaction to *lighten* color will fail - screen, overlay, color dodge, etc. You will have to find another way to achieve what you are after. In some instances, you can work in RGB and then Flatten Transparency before converting to CMYK.

Comment: Now here's an interesting tidbit in the multiple vector-art tools discussion - just tested in Affinity Designer - screen and hard light I used in a file for a different question worked almost exactly as expected when items and then entire document were converted to CMYK. Slight diminution in the dynamic range of the result, but overall, quite passable.

Comment: Yeah, I don't know *why* the modes break in CMYK Illustrator.. I mean the modes work fine in CMYK Photoshop.... Logically they should work in Illustrator. After all it's just color layering based on math for a final preview/appearance..... but they have just never worked in Illustrator.